# Virtualenvwrapper alternative for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I just wanted to setup a small development environment with Python 3.

I had no problems installing `pip` and `virtualenv`, however `virtualenvwrapper` does not seem to support Python 3 yet (as it states on the [mercurial repo](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/overview)).

Trying to install it with pip yields the following error:

```
  Running setup.py install for virtualenvwrapper

    changing mode of build/scripts-3.2/virtualenvwrapper.sh from 644 to 755
    Skipping installation of /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/__init__.py (namespace package)
    Installing /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper-2.11.1-py3.2-nspkg.pth
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to 755
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 137
        print '  %-10s -- %s' % (ep.name, inspect.getdoc(plugin) or '')
                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/user_scripts.py", line 40
        except OSError, msg:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed virtualenvwrapper
Cleaning up...
```

Even though the last line states successfully installed I can not invoke the virtualenvwrapper commands.

Does anyone know an alternative to it that works with Python 3?

**EDIT:**

For anyone coming back to this question - a version that supports Python 3 has just been released: [Virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) (30/01/2012).

Comment: Anything wrong with just using `virtualenv`? Works fine for my current Python 3 project...

Comment: It's not really a big problem - you just get used to the comfort of the wrapper.

Comment: The Python part is only 3 fairly small files. You can probably port it quite easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally I would say "Fork it and port it". It's a small program, under a 1000 lines of code, most of which is written in clear and best practices by Dough Hellman. Porting it is probably going to be dead simple and a good exercise.

However in this case, all you need to do is notice in the bitbucket page that there are two pull requests waiting already, one which is a Python 3 compatibility fix. You can probably check out and use that one. https://bitbucket.org/dakra/virtualenvwrapper/overview

Comment: I knew I forgot to look somewhere ... even though the forks would have been a really obvious place to look.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.3 comes with an integrated virtual environnement solution called [venv](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html)